# WordPress Site missing Dashboard after migration

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, migration

I had a WordPress installation which I recently moved to a new Linux host. My host is for three website. I already had a WordPress site at the home directory (/public_html/). The later installation is at 'public_html/mukharsamvad.com'. The first WordPress installation is working fine. But the website with domain name 'mukharsamvad.com' is not showing any media (photos etc.). Even after logging into 'wp-admin' it doesn't directs to dashboard. Admin bar appears at the top, but doesn't have any menu or option.

After checking the URLs of images, I have found as 'http://mukharsamvad.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/nitish-kumar-11-1.jpg/'. It is treating it as directory. Please recommend me fixes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it sounds like you are missing file of Wordpress I would suggest you to compare each directly with installed WordPress if you still don't solve problem then take backup of migrating WordPress installation do fresh installation then override the backup files

Comment: Removed old installation and re-install WordPress. After restoring database, problem with image urls solved, but Dashboard still missing.

Comment: have you checked database details? are they same in new installation if not then you have to set in manually in config file

Answer (score 0):

Removed old installation and re-install WordPress. After restoring database, problem with image urls solved, but Dashboard still missing.

Here what you can do

- check by deactivating all the plugins
- change the theme

if not worked , switch for theme editor.

- install classic editor plugin and enable it

if this not worked  ,

- inspect element & check console for errors.

Comment: How can I change the theme without access to Dashboard. Please help as I am new to WordPress

Comment: I have changed the theme through database to default (twenty*) themes. But Dashboard not restored.